# Prestashop is not sending order emails to the eshop

Tags: php, email, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have an issue with a Prestashop 1.6.1.6 where the "eshop" doesn't receive any **order** email, but the customer receives them properly. The Prestashop is hosted on a shared hosting server with cPanel, running PHP 5.5.

I have checked the above so far:

1. Under ***Preferences->Store Contacts->Shop email***, the email is correct.
2. After a successful order as a customer, in ***cPanel->Mail->Mail Trace***, i can see the delivery attempts to customer's email but not to "eshop" email.
3. Have installed, enabled and configured properly the module "Mail Alerts", entered 1 and more emails in E-mail addresses, but didn't receive any email as the "eshop".
4. Tried the option: ***Advanced Parameters->E-mail->TEST YOUR EMAIL CONFIGURATION->Send a test email***, with the "eshop's" email address and it worked, bot with PHP mail() and with SMTP.
5. I have sent an email via the contact form (as a test customer) to Webmaster and to Customer Service and both the client and the "eshop" received the mail.
6. Sent a test email via thunderbird to the "eshop's" email address and it worked.
7. Made a new registration as a test customer with a valid email address. The test customer received the "Welcome" email, but the "eshop" didn't receive anything. (i am not really sure if the "eshop" should get any notification mail in this case to be sure, but i tried it).

What i understood so far, is that the mail functionality works for contact forms, test emails via Prestashop, test emails via thunderbird, but not for any kind of orders.

I don't know if there is something else to try to find the problem.

Is there any other option in Prestashop, which prevents the order emails to be sent to the "eshop"? 
Is this a bug in Order Functionality?

Any idea would be useful since i don't know what else i can do. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if in "eshop" you meant merchant, by default Prestashop does not send these notifications to "admin",

install the **Mail alerts** module, and there are options to send different types of emails to provided addresses.

Comment: Thank you, the Mail Alerts module solved my problem BUT i had to create a folder inside mailalerts->mails, named as my main language abbreviation and copy there all emails from "en" folder. English is not supported in this Prestashop installation. I was pretty sure that in previous installations the "eshop" was receiving the order emails, probably because of that module(?). Still not really sure, i will test it to be fair. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It would look that you have the email template in "modules / mailalerts / mail / in / new_order.html"

Regards,